conda-build TEST FAILED due to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarmor_runtime_006359'
I have a conda package that is obfuscated by pyarmor. My code is in a folder name "my_project" inside the dist folder created when I run pyarmor obfuscation. I placed the pyproject.toml and meta.yaml directly inside the dist folder. Inside "my_project", the pyarmor_runtime_006359 with the pyarmor_runtime.so is there. When I run "conda-build .", I get a TEST FAILED result as it is complaining that the init.py inside "my_project" cannot find the module pyarmor_runtime_006359.
I checked the directory mentioned in the error which is ..lib/python3.12/site-packages/my_project/ but I see the pyarmor_runtime_006359 directory there with the pyarmor_runtime.so. I tested by running python in the file path and tried "from pyarmor_runtime_006359 import pyarmor" and it works.
